# Loop through SQL to get count, if value of all inputs are 0, disable submit button

Tags: php, jquery

My products are split up into variable and fixed pricing. Based on ajax when clicked on plus or minus inputs to add or delete items to the sidebar. Its coded to make the disabled submit button enabled when the price in the sidebar is more then 0 etc. That's fine and works. However on the refresh regardless of the amount of items added, the submit button will go back to disabled. The inputs value change from 0 to the item amount.
We need to validate the submit button that if any of those values are higher then 0, then the button should be enabled. It only becomes enabled again once you add or delete an item. Here is the markup.

```
<div class="select-price">
<?php
    $order_id   = $_SESSION['orderid'];
    $addonID    = get_the_id();
    if($_SESSION['currenttrip']>1){
        $order_item_amount  = 0;
    }else{
        $qty = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT order_item_total, order_item_name, order_item_amount FROM fcb_order_item WHERE order_id=$order_id AND order_item_addon_id=$addonID");
        $order_item_amount  = ($qty->order_item_amount) ? $qty->order_item_amount : 0;
    }

    if(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'fcb_addon_pricing_type', true) == 'fixed')
    {
        $max     = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'fcb_addon_max_amount', true);
        $options = array_fill(1, $max, 'option');

        echo '<input data-addon-id="'.get_the_id().'" data-price="'.$price.'" type="button" value="-" class="qtyminus new-add-item add-service-item plus left '.$addonID.'" data-type="minus" field="quantity" />';
        echo '<input class="airport-value qty qty-'.get_the_id().'" type="number" name="quantity" value="'.$order_item_amount.'" />';
        echo '<input data-addon-id="'.get_the_id().'" data-price="'.$price.'" type="button" value="+" class="qtyplus new-add-item add-service-item minus right '.$addonID.'" data-type="plus" field="quantity" />';

    } elseif (get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'fcb_addon_pricing_type', true) == 'variable') {

        $options = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'fcb_variable', true);

        echo '<input data-addon-id="'.get_the_id().'" data-price="'.$options[0]['price'].'" type="button" value="-" class="qtyminus new-add-item add-service-item plus left '.$addonID.'" data-type="minus" field="quantity" />';
        echo '<input class="airport-value qty qty-'.get_the_id().'" type="number" name="quantity" value="'.$order_item_amount.'" />';
        echo '<input data-addon-id="'.get_the_id().'" data-price="'.$options[0]['price'].'" type="button" value="+" class="qtyplus new-add-item add-service-item minus right '.$addonID.'" data-type="plus" field="quantity" />';

    }
?>
</div>
```

using something on the lines of

```
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) { }
```

but not sure how to loop through two different sets of options being variable and fixed. If they all are 0 then disable the submit button. If any one has a value of 1 then enable it and let the customer continue to payment

EDIT

here is the ajax that adds and deletes the items to the sidebar and the price etc.

```
//Arrival First Track suvarnabhumi
if(addonid==126){
    if($quantity.val()>0){
        $('.plus218').removeClass('add-service-item');
        $('.minus218').removeClass('add-service-item');
    }else{
        $('.plus218').addClass('add-service-item');
        $('.minus218').addClass('add-service-item');
    }
}

//Depeature First Track suvarnabhumi
if(addonid==283){
    if($quantity.val()>0){
        $('.plus1597').removeClass('add-service-item');
        $('.minus1597').removeClass('add-service-item');
    }else{
        $('.plus1597').addClass('add-service-item');
        $('.minus1597').addClass('add-service-item');
    }
}


//Arrival First Track don muang airport
if(addonid==216){

    if($quantity.val()>0){
        $('.plus218').removeClass('add-service-item');
        $('.minus218').removeClass('add-service-item');
    }else{
        $('.plus218').addClass('add-service-item');
        $('.minus218').addClass('add-service-item');
    }

}

var amount = parseInt($quantity.val());
var total = parseInt($(this).attr('data-price')) * amount;

if (total > 0) {
    $('.main-amount-' + addonid).html('');
    $('.main-amount-' + addonid).html(total);
}

console.log(addonid+'-'+amount+'-'+total)

$('.spinner').html('loading');
$('.addon-list').hide();
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: myAjax.ajaxurl,
    data: {
        action: 'fcb_add_item_to_order',
        addonid: addonid,
        amount: amount,
        total: total,
        option: option
    },
    beforeSend: function () {
    },
    success: function (response){

        //var price = data.split('~');
        if(response>0){
            $('.return-total-save').html(response);
            $('.payment-for-airport').prop('disabled', true );
        }

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: myAjax.ajaxurl,
            data: {
                action: 'get_sidebar_addons', // get Items for SB
            },
            beforeSend: function () {
            },
            success: function (data) {

                var $content = $('#acc-' + tripcount + ' .addon-list')
                $content.html(data);

                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url : myAjax.ajaxurl,
                    data: {
                        action: 'get_sidebar_total', // get total for SB
                    },
                    beforeSend: function () {
                    },
                    success: function (data) {

                        $('.spinner').html('');
                        $('.addon-list').show();
                        var $content = $('.total-main-price span');
                        $content.html(data);
                        $('#currency').trigger('change');

                        if (total > 0) {
                            alert("price has increased lets make a payment");
                            $('.payment-for-airport').prop('disabled', false);
                        }
                        if (data == 0) {
                            alert("price is 0");
                            $('.payment-for-airport').prop('disabled', true );
                        }

                    }
                });

            }
        });

    }
});
});
```

Comment: When you refresh are your products still on the list? It would be helpfull to see your ``submit`` button and your JS code.

Comment: All products are still there, the values of the inputs gets stored, the sidebar is still showing the correct amounts and price. But if you added a product the submit button would be disabled still.

Comment: I don't get your code, and can't see your ``submit`` button and where you update its status, but you could add a function to enable it on load after sidebar load.